# What is the difference between aes and aes_string (ggplot2) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

With missing background in informatics I have difficulties to understand the differences between `aes` and `aes_string` in ggplot2 and its implications for daily usage.

From the description (`?aes_string`) I was able to understand that both `describe how variables in the data are mapped to visual properties (aesthetics) of geom`.

Furthermore it is said that `aes uses non-standard evaluation to capture the variable names.` whereas `aes_string` uses `regular evaluation`.

From example code it is clear that both produce the same output (`a list of unevaluated expressions`):

```
> aes_string(x = "mpg", y = "wt")
List of 2
 $ x: symbol mpg
 $ y: symbol wt
> aes(x = mpg, y = wt)
List of 2
 $ x: symbol mpg
 $ y: symbol wt
```

`Non-standard evaluation` is described by [Hadley Wickham in his book *Advanced R*](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) as a method to not only call the values of a functions argument but also the code that produced them.

I would assume that `regular evaluation` in opposition only calls the values from the function, but I did not find a source to confirm this assumption. Furthermore it is unclear to me how those two differ and why this should be relevant to me when I use the package.

On the [inside-R website](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ggplot2/docs/aes_string) it is mentioned that `aes_string is particularly useful when writing functions that create plots because you can use strings to define the aesthetic mappings, rather than having to mess around with expressions.`

But in that sense it is unclear to me why I should ever use `aes` and not opt always for `aes_string` whenever using `ggplot2`... In that sense it would help me to find some clarifications on those concepts and a practical hint for daily usage.

Comment: Please note that `aes_string()` is now soft-deprecated, and `.data[[]]` is preferred. So previously: `aes_string(x = chr_variable)` but now: `aes(x = .data[[chr_variable]])`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`aes` saves you some typing as you don't need the quotes. That is all. You are of course free to always use `aes_string`. You should use `aes_string` if you want to pass the variable names programmatically.

Internally `aes` uses `match.call` for the non-standard evaluation. Here is a simple example for illustration:

```
fun <- function(x, y) as.list(match.call())
str(fun(a, b))
#List of 3
# $  : symbol fun
# $ x: symbol a
# $ y: symbol b
```

For comparison:

```
library(ggplot2)
str(aes(x = a, y = b))
#List of 2
# $ x: symbol a
# $ y: symbol b
```

The symbols are evaluated at a later stage.

`aes_string` uses `parse` to achieve the same:

```
str(aes_string(x = "a", y = "b"))
#List of 2
# $ x: symbol a
# $ y: symbol b
```

Comment: unfortunately, that's not so simple: ggplot does not have the same plotting-behaviour depending on whether you used `aes` or `aes_string`. It messes up the memory in different ways and plots different things... see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439266/list-for-multiple-plots-from-loop-ggplot2-list-elements-being-overwritten. ggplot is a huge problem in itself

Comment: "You should use aes_string if you want to pass the variable names programmatically" is no longer true since ggplot 3.0.0 and its support of `!!`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53168593/2270475 .