# R: Filling list with ggplots is resulting in strange results... A bug in R?

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I found a very strange thing in R, if I would not know better (and I don't) I would say it's a bug in R...

```
library(ggplot2, gridExtra)
data(mtcars)

gglist <- list()
for (colname in names(mtcars)) {
  gg <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=get(colname),y=mpg)) + geom_point() + labs(x=colname)
  nextelnr <- length(gglist)+1
  gglist[[nextelnr]] <- gg

  print(gglist[[nextelnr]])
  if(nextelnr>2) {
    print(gglist[[nextelnr-1]])
  }

}
print(gglist[[3]])
do.call("grid.arrange", c(gglist, ncol=floor(sqrt(length(gglist)))))
```

What is happending: The plots are printed correctly from within the loop, however the plot outside the loops repeat the same (namely the last) ggplot - but with different x-labels.

I know by now that using

```
aes_string(x=colname,y="mpg")
```

solves the problem, but it does not answer the question.

How is that possible?

Comment: See MrFlick's answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439266/list-for-multiple-plots-from-loop-ggplot2-list-elements-being-overwritten "the problem is that ggplot() waits until you print the plot to resolve the variables in the aes() command.[...] However, at the end of the loop, D will only have the last value."

Comment: @scoa Thanks, now I know better :-). If you would Post your comment as an answer, I can except it and you get credit. (Otherwise I will post it later as an answer.)

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate, I think it's better to redirect to the other answer