# Lapply and for loop produce different result when creating graphs dynamically

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, lapply, gridextra

first time asking question here so if I mess up something, please let me know I'll be happy to fix it.

While trying to dynamically create multiple graphs generated by `ggplot2` and then print the graphs using `gridExtra::grid.arrange`, I noticed that using a `for` loop or using `lapply` produce different results.

Surprisingly, while `lapply` produces the expected result, the graphs created with the `for` loop end up with having all the same `y` data.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

gen.plot <- function(df, x.colName, y.colName, title,
                            movavg.period) {
  # print(y.colName)
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df[[x.colName]],
                      y = df[[y.colName]])) +
    geom_line() +
    xlab("Time") +
    ylab("Value") +
    ggtitle(title)

  return(p)
}

titles <- c("down", "mid", "up")
df <- data.frame(tick = seq(0, 10, 1),
                 down = seq(2, 1, -0.1),
                 mid = rep(3, 11),
                 up = seq(5,6, 0.1))

plots.list <- list()
for(t in titles) {
  plots.list[[length(plots.list) + 1]] <- gen.plot(df, "tick", 
                                            t, t, 2)
}
grid.arrange(grobs = plots.list, nrow = 3)

plots.list <- lapply(titles, FUN =  function(t, lapply.df) {
  gen.plot(lapply.df, "tick", 
        t, t, 2)
}, lapply.df = df)

grid.arrange(grobs = plots.list, nrow = 3)
```

Now, where it becomes really weird, is that if you uncomment the `print` call in the function that prints out the **y.colName** variable, the `for` loop works as expected. But it only works if you print out this specific variable, not any of the other function variable. Also, as you can see in the code, the **y.colName** variable is used in the title of the graph, and the title is correct in every graph.

Also, I've tried taking the code out of the function but it provides the same results and the `print` call trick does not work anymore.

I can't post image without 10 reputation so links will have to do.

Here is what I get with the `for` loop:
[forloop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ijCz.jpg)

Here is what I get with `lapply`:
[lapply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pQ5c.jpg)

Here is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Ireland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Ireland.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Ireland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=English_Ireland.1252    

attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
  [1] gridExtra_2.3 ggplot2_2.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] labeling_0.3     colorspace_1.3-2 scales_0.5.0     compiler_3.4.3  
[5] lazyeval_0.2.0   plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.4.3      pillar_1.2.1    
[9] gtable_0.2.0     tibble_1.4.2     yaml_2.1.14      Rcpp_0.12.16    
[13] grid_3.4.3       rlang_0.2.0      munsell_0.4.3
```

Please, if you understand what's happening here, explain it to me, help me get my sleep back.

Comment: When you use a for loop, only the last iteration is rendered. You can read the explanation to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439266/list-for-multiple-plots-from-loop-ggplot2-list-elements-being-overwritten). [This](https://www.data-imaginist.com/2017/beneath-the-canvas/) is also a good read that goes into how ggplot creates a graph.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gen.plot <- function(df, x.colName, y.colName, title,
                     movavg.period) {
  # print(y.colName)
  p <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x = x.colName,
                             y = y.colName)) +
    geom_line() +
    xlab("Time") +
    ylab("Value") +
    ggtitle(title)

  return(p)
}
```

It should give you consist and correct results whichever method you use to implement it (i.e., `lapply` or `for` loop). Using `ggplot2` in this way allows you to specify the variable names using a string. And you should be specifying variable names and not giving `aes` the entire column from the data frame.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Lyngbakr. It does produce the same results for both `lapply` and `for` using `aes_string`.
However, what I'm more interested in is why it does not produce the same results in the case that I showed previously. What's the underlying difference between `for` and `lapply` that makes the code works in one case and not the other, as well as why printing the content of the variable change the outcome of the code.