# Variable geom_text is overwritten when plots saved in list

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to organize several dozens of plots using `ggarrange`, so I have setup a loop in which I save each plot in a list. Each plot differs from each other with different data, title, etc. Everything works perfectly until I try to use `geom_text` to place some text inside the plot. When the plots are saved in the list, each plot inherits the `geom_text` from the last plot in the list. I don't know how to avoid this.

```
my.list=vector("list", length = 2);
dt=data.table(x=c(1,100,100000),y=c(1,100,100000))
plotname=c('first','second')

for (i in 1:length(my.list)) {
 my.list[[i]]=ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = x, y = y ))  + geom_point(size=1.5,aes(color=c('red'))) + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) 
+ scale_color_manual(values='red') 
+ theme_bw() + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='light grey', colour='black'),legend.position = "none") 
+ geom_text(inherit.aes=FALSE,aes(x=500, y=100000, label=paste0('NRMSE:',i))) + ggtitle(paste0(plotname[i])) + coord_equal() 
+ geom_abline(slope=1) 
+ scale_y_log10(breaks = c(1,10,100,1000,10000,100000),limits=c(1,100000)) 
+ scale_x_log10(breaks = c(1,10,100,1000,10000,1000000),limits=c(1,100000)) 
+ labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) 
+ theme_bw() + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='light grey', colour='black'),legend.position = "none")
}
```

after this I do

```
plotosave=ggarrange(plotlist=my.list)
```

[image]

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23439266/680068

Comment: @zx8754 I have tried aes_string but it's not working because when I use ggarrange then it complains about "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'NRMSE' not found", so it's not the same solution even if the question is probably the same problem.

Comment: We have the answer to your specific problem, linked post just explains the "why" it happens. I'd keep it closed. Feel free vote to re-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *lapply* instead of *forloop* works fine:

```
my.list <- lapply(1:2, function(i) {
  ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = x, y = y ))  + 
    geom_point(size=1.5) + 
    labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='light grey', colour='black'),
          legend.position = "none") + 
    geom_text(inherit.aes=FALSE,aes(x=50000, y=100000, 
                                    label=paste0('NRMSE:',i))) + 
    ggtitle(paste0(plotname[i]))
  })

ggarrange(plotlist = my.list)
```

Note: the issue is not with *ggarrange*.

---

[Roland:](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland)

> The plot is build when you print the ggplot object. Anything that is not part of the data passed will be taken from the enclosing environment at exactly that time point. If you use the iterator of a for loop in the plot, it has its last value then (or any value you change it to later on). lapply avoids the issue because of the stuff explained in the Note in its documentation.

---

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23439781/680068):

> the problem is that *ggplot()* waits until you print the plot to resolve the variables in the *aes()* command.

Comment: thank you that solves the issue even with the updated quote I have posted. This is puzzling indeed, I hope someone else can give us an explication.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know *why* this occurs but if you remove `aes` from `geom_text` it works.

```
library(ggplot2)

my.list = vector("list", length = 2)
dt = data.table::data.table(x=c(1,100,100000),y=c(1,100,100000))
plotname = c('first','second')

for (i in 1:length(my.list)) {

  my.list[[i]]= ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = x, y = y ))  + 
                 geom_point(size=1.5) + 
                 labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
                 theme_bw() + 
                 theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='light grey', colour='black'),
                       legend.position = "none") + 
                 geom_text(x=50000, y=100000, label=paste0('NRMSE:',i)) + 
                 ggtitle(paste0(plotname[i]))
}
plotosave = ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist=my.list)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately I need to have aes() otherwise geom_text is not displayed in my case. I am sorry but I posted a simplified ggplot call but I realized only after your answer that something else is interfering, my original call is as follows: